# Searching std::string between a limit

Tags: c++, string, stl

if you know the start and end positions in string from where to begin and end the search. For example -

```
string s = StringStringString

|S |t |r |i |n |g |S |t |r |i |n |g |S |t |r |i |n |g
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

How would you find "tr" in the string specifying the the position to begin search is at index 6 and the position to end the search is index 9.

I'm trying a set a limit of search so it wouldn't go beyond it.

Comment: Someone has downvoted the post and answer I accepted. wasn't my question clear enough?

Comment: Much as with most anything democratic, sometimes votes just display the ignorance of the voter.

Comment: @Jerry The downvote was me - the question could have been answered by reading any introductory book on C++, something Dave17 seems adverse to doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to limit the length of the sequence that gets traversed (presumably because the string is very long compared to the interesting region), use [`std::search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/) and pass it the corresponding iterators into the string.

Answer (score 1):

Given `start` as the position where you want to start searching, and `stop` as the position where you want to stop searching:

```
int pos = your_string.find("tr", start);

if (pos == std::string::npos || pos > stop)
    // it wasn't found.
```

This assumes that what you're giving as `stop` is that last position at which a match can begin. So (for example) if you want to match a substring that's four characters long, it can extend up to three characters past the `stop` position. If you want to assure the *end* of the substring is before the stop point, you'd subtract the length of the substring from `stop` when you compare to `pos`

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the if statement but rather finding a function to do that :S

Comment: what is "npos"? std::string::npos? – std::string::find returns a size_t.

Comment: @tusbar:actually, it returns a `size_type`, which may or may not be the same as `size_t`. According to §21.3.6.1/2, it returns npos if the substring wasn't found.

Comment: @Dave17: That's just some ultra-pedantry. `string::size_type` comes from `Allocator::size_type`, and default allocator's `size_type` is `size_t`. Now it could be possible that you have a string with a different allocator and different size type, but `std::string` by definition is `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

---

```
std::string str("StringStringString");
std::string::size_type found = str.find("tr", 6, 9 - 6);
```

Comment: The return from find is not size_t, and you've failed to account for the possibility that the substring isn't found.

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to find a string in another one. It's up to him to read the documentation. – It makes more sense to me to return a non-signed value for a size or a position. But you're right, it returns `std::string::size_type`.

Comment: Ok, first I thought the code would work but it didn't when i actually tried. the third parameter here is the length of characters to search for, it doesn't provide a limit of search.

Comment: @Jerry: I think that assigning the result of `string::find` to a `size_t` is safe almost always. `size_t` is a type large enough for the size of any object, and it's generally considered safe (although not actually guaranteed) to assume that string holds the char data in a single array. Hence the size of a string cannot exceed the limit on the size of an object. A more pressing problem with this solution is that the third param to `find` isn't the length of the region of the string to search, it's the length of the string being searched for. This code is looking for the sequence t, r, NUL.

Comment: agree with @cpx, the third parameter limits the number of characters to search from needle ( in our case "tr", 9-6 = 3 > 2 so it will search the whole needle starting from the 6th position ). You can test out the theory by searching for something outside the bounds.